# Rendering static files via docker

Tags: docker, containers, docker-image

I am new to working with docker.

Is there anything I need to add to properly render static images on my server?

I'm working with a node.js express backend, and my configuration is correct, however the images are not rendering in prod. Thinking this could be a docker thing as that is via how I am deploying, but I am just not familiar with...

My images are located at:

```
Base Directory > public > icons
```

Here is a copy of my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.15.4-buster-slim@sha256:c8b73b9968457ee4969050955031efe0943d7770e38eeec2943debefd4d28cfd
RUN  apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y wget gnupg ca-certificates \
     && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
     && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
     && apt-get update \

& apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
     && wget --quiet https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/master/wait-for-it.sh -O /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh \
     && chmod +x /usr/sbin/wait-for-it.sh
ENV NODE_ENV="docker"

WORKDIR /


ADD ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN npm install


COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: Try copying sources first and then run npm install. Docker file executes command in sequence. {COPY . .} needs to be first then {RU N npm install}

Comment: @veereshpatil nope, that did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Quetion about `however the images are not rendering in prod`,it is do `docker build . `failed ,or build success?In my thinking, is you build success but not start a container?

Comment: @bigpangl build is a success. I This is through my container registry in digital ocean

Comment: @KirtM9 In fact,I do not understand .... Get error when running  contrianer, or when building  image ? If just build staic file, would use docker run to build and save files to local path. If deploy server,use nginx after building  files or just run node server in container?